# Menú con do while se tilda

Tags: c++

El problema es que después de ingresar más de dos veces en el case 1, la pantalla queda tildada en `Presione una tecla para continuar....`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

void menu(){
    cout<<"1: Ingresar numero "<<endl;
    cout<<"2: Eliminar numero "<<endl;
    cout<<"3: Visualizar numero "<<endl;
    cout<<"4: Salir "<<endl;    
}

int main(){
    int op,num;
    do{
        menu();
        cin >> op;

        switch(op){
            case 1:
                cout<<"Ingrese Numer\n";
                cin>>num;
                break;           
            case 2:
                cout<<"opcion2";
                break;        
            case 3:
                cout<<"opcion3";
                break;    
        }

        system("pause");      
        system("cls");

    }while(op!=4);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿Para qué pones un system pause dentro del do-while?

Comment: Para que la información devuelta no se borre.

Comment: Pues elimina el `cls` también, y así no se borran nunca, y te quitas el `system("pause")` de en medio, que aparte de ser una fea costumbre, solo tiene sentido cuando programas con `Dev-C++`. Por lo demás, con cualquier otro IDE o plataforma, el `system("pause")` sobra, y en Linux o Mac ni siquiera funciona.

Comment: Use cin.clear() despues de cin y el programa funciona ...sabes por qué?

Comment: Porque escribes algo y luego Intro, el Intro es también un carácter. Cuando lees, por ejemplo, `cin >> num`, `cin` lee la entrada hasta el Intro, que al no ser un número, se detiene, y el carácter `Intro` no se consume. Ese `Intro` pendiente luego es visto por `system("pause")`, y luego no sé exáctamente qué pasa. Supongo que el `pause` ve dicho intro y considera que el usuario ha pulsado una tecla, entrando en la siguiente iteración. El caso es que, cuando haces `cin.clear()`, borras todo lo que haya pendiente en la entrada estándar, borrando dicho intro pendiente.

Comment: @Peregring-lk Deberías escribir ese comentario como respuesta para que pueda ser aceptado como tal.

Comment: @eferion Es que no estoy seguro de sí exáctamente eso lo que le pasa, pero bueno, lo pasaré a respuesta.

Comment: @Peregring-lk Yo diría que el problema puede ser dependiente del SO, aun así lo que comentas suena mínimamente convincente... es por cosas de estas por las que no suelo recomendar llamar a `system` bajo ninguna circunstancia

Comment: @eferion En Dev-C++ + Win es obligatorio, sino la terminal se cierra y no ves los resultados, y suele ser una IDE que los profesores, en su infinita torpeza y falta de horas de programación, suelen recomendar, porque poco más conocen.

Comment: @Peregring-lk eso no es por dev-c++ sino porque el estándar de C (aplicable también a C++) tiene una implementación muy pobre para la gestión de la consola y no incluye, por ejemplo, programar entradas sin eco.

Comment: @eferion Esta conversación me suena de algo. Cuando se termina el programa, se cierra la entrada estándar (obvio), no todos los programas son interactivos. Y la consola Dev-C++ cierra la terminal cuando se cierra la entrada estándar. Y que C++ ponga restricciones sobre ttys, o consolas interactivas y las que no lo son, intérpretes, sesiones remotas, en fin, "consola" es un término con un abanico muy amplio de posibilidades, todas responsabilidad del SO y/o del IDE.

Comment: @peregring-lk si existiese una entrada sin eco en el estándar la instrucción `system("pause")` se podría emular elegantemente con solo dos líneas de código

Comment: @eferion Si Dev-C++ no cerrara la terminal, no haría falta un `system("pause");`. Además, se puede sustituir elegantemente con un `char c; std::cin>>c;`. El problema es de Dev-C++ o de terminales que no hagan un buen uso de la entrada/salida según su contexto de uso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aunque no estoy seguro de qué problema estás teniendo exáctamente, supongo que serás víctima de un error común: no sabes como funciona la entrada estándar.

Creo que lo que te pasa es que, escribes algo, y luego intro, el intro es también un carácter. Cuando lees, por ejemplo, `cin >> num`, `cin` lee la entrada hasta el intro, que al no ser un número, se detiene, y el carácter Intro no se consume. Ese intro pendiente luego es visto por `system("pause")`, y luego no sé exáctamente qué estará pasando en tu programa.

Supongo que el `"pause"` ve dicho intro y considera que el usuario ha pulsado una tecla, entrando en la siguiente iteración.

Comment: `cin.clear` únicamente limpia los flags del buffer de entrada... para borrar los caracteres es necesario llamar a `cin.ignore`

Comment: @eferion Gracias por la aclaración.